# Low pass butterworth filter is distorting

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter

my low pass filter keeps distorting and I'm at a loss to explain why. It calculates the correct coefficients, but distorts everything. The code is as follows. It's driving me mad. What's weird is my high pass works perfectly and it's coded in a similar way, but with a negative b1 coefficent and the same a1 and a2 coeffcients.

```
float cutoff = 100.00f * M_PI * 2.0f;
float c      = 2.0f * sampleRate;
float q      = sqrt(2.0f)/2.0f;

g_a1LP = (2.0f * pow(c, 2.0f) - (2.0f * pow(cutoff, 2.0f))) / (pow(c, 2.0f) + ((cutoff*c)/q) + pow(cutoff, 2.0f));
g_a2LP = -(pow(c, 2.0f)  + pow(cutoff, 2.0f) - (cutoff*c)/q ) / (pow(c, 2.0f) + ((cutoff*c)/q) + pow(cutoff, 2.0f));
g_b0LP = 1.0f;
g_b1LP = 2.0f;
g_b2LP = 1.0f;
```

The values for `a1 = 1.97985` and `a2 = -0.98005`. The actual processing is then

```
//Low pass
            g_lastLowPassOutSamples[0] = (g_b2LP * g_lastLowPassInSamples[2]) + (g_b1LP * g_lastLowPassInSamples[1]) + (g_b0LP * g_lastLowPassInSamples[0]) +  (g_a2LP * g_lastLowPassOutSamples[2]) + (g_a1LP * g_lastLowPassOutSamples[1]);
```

Comment: Nope. I've progressed past that problem.

Comment: What is it filtering?  Why do you say it is distorting whatever it is filtering?

Comment: No feedback on Jim's question?

Comment: My apologies. It turned out the magnitude was through the roof, hence the distortion. Thanks for taking the time guys.

Comment: It was filtering a sin sweep.